# Re-use LocalTime variable for differents methods

Tags: java, java-time

I would like to know if it is possible to create a LocalTime variable to re-use in different methods.

I have a class `Notes` and the next methods

```
 public void createNote(Note note) {
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Mexico_City"));
        note.setCreatedAt(now);
        note.setUpdatedAt(now);
 }
public void updateNote(int noteId, Note modifyNote) {
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Mexico_City"));
        note.setTitle(modifyNote.getTitle());
        note.setContent(modifyNote.getContent());
        note.setUpdatedAt(now);
 }
 public void updateAllNotes() {
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Mexico_City"));
        update.set("updatedAt", now);
 }
```

All works fine with this implementation. The output is the next

```
Note1
Created At: 12:01:03
Last Update: 15:24:41
```

But I'm looking for something like

```
private LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Mexico_City"));

 public void createNote(Note note) {
        note.setCreatedAt(now);
        note.setUpdatedAt(now);
 }
public void updateNote(int noteId, Note modifyNote) {
        note.setTitle(modifyNote.getTitle());
        note.setContent(modifyNote.getContent());
        note.setUpdatedAt(now);
 }
 public void updateAllNotes() {
        update.set("updatedAt", now);
 }
```

I tried this but what I got It's the same time.

Example

```
Note1
Created At: 12:01:03
Last Update: 12:01:03
```

Comment: Create a method: `LocalTime now() { return LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Mexico_City")); }`

Comment: The output in the second example is what should be expected. You are creating one LocalTime object and using it in multiple places without reassigning it in-between. So It will have one value and that value will stay fixed. If you want to always get the current local time for every method call then the first example code is the correct way to do it.  There is no way to have an object magically update its value every time it is referenced in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was asking this, to know if it was a good practice to do that